# Angular Evaluating Ajax Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

How do I evaluate a template, recevied via AJAX?

Let's say I have a directive, that sets a click-listener to its host element, so on click it makes an ajax-call, receives some angular-based template, evaluates it, and shows some modal popup?

The main problem is that as a client, I dont exactly know what template to fetch, the server handles that, based on received parameters

```
$http.post( '... url ...' , {
  'param': value,
   ... 
}).success(function (ans) {
 // evaluate and create popup here
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directive's template could have a `<div ng-iclude="scopedVar.templateUrl"></div>`

Whenever `scopedVar.templateUrl` changes, the template will get loaded and compiled/linked (all this magic you're missing). Keep in mind that `ng-include` will also cache the template inside `$templateCache` (will only be asked once).

Comment: Thank you very much! That was not the solution I finnaly applied, but this made me think in right direction.